# IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.1 and Subversion 1.8 working copy format

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.1; the Svn repository server is 1.8.5

When trying to check out from repository I have the options "1.8 format" disabled

In [idea subversion integration web help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-subversion-integration.html) prerequisite section, is stated that

> IntelliJ IDEA's Subversion integration does not require a standalone Subversion client. All you need is an account in your Subversion repository

Why do I have "1.8 format" option disabled/grayed out? Do I need to install some 'subversion native client'? Am I missing something?

[image: Disabled 1.8 format]

I'm running on a windows 2003 server sp2.

Comment: Am I the only one having this issue? I think I did something terribly wrong!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is grayed out because the svn client is needed.
[jetbrains blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/12/subversion-1-8-and-intellij-idea-13/)

I've installed [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) and the option "1.8 format" is now available.

Comment: Installing Silk SVN did not work for me in Windows 7 (may be a reboot / restart of studio would have worked). But, when I installed Tortoise SVN 1.8.9, it worked. It was update of tortoise svn as I had tortoise svn 1.7 already installed on my machine. The install required restart of certain applications like studio, notepad++

Answer (score 3):

Please specify full path to svn client in “Version Control” -> “Subversion” project settings.

This is /opt/local/bin/svn in my machine